# How to use @using mynamespace in .js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to put following code in my .js file. It is developed in MVC 5 for using resx file. It is working well if I put this script in view. But is shows error when I put that code in external js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @using myres = Microsoft.IT.GetDevices.Web.Properties;
    $("#divlblNewsSource").text("@myres.Resource.NewsSources");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run razor on script files. For this you should use a cshtml file.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable and assign the value from the resx file and inside your external JS use this variable for setting the text value.

**Inside View**

```
@using myres = Microsoft.IT.GetDevices.Web.Properties;
var temp = "@myres.Resource.NewsSources";
```

**Inside external JS**

```
$("#divlblNewsSource").text(temp);
```

**EDIT:-**

**You can use <kbd>[RazorJS](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS/)</kbd>**

It allows `C#` or `VB.NET` inside your JavaScript Files. Also contains an http handler for serving, when needed, those files.

Comment: It is not working. Also I want full code in js file. It is like partial code in view and partial in js file.